# wordpress sidebar content in different languages

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I am developing a site in wordpress.I want the particular page from the site in four different languages(English,spanish,french and Dutch).I have used a plugin called **WP Native Dashboard**.Using this I am able to get the page content in four different languages.I used the combobox to select the language and display the content.This works fine...

I am creating a new page,select the language ,and writing the content in it.For same content in different language i am just writing the page id besides the language name as follows  :

[image]

Main problem is about the sidebars,footer and the header content.I have one set of sidebar,footer and header in English language.When I select the different language (for example french) the sidebar,footer and header content is displayed in English.

If i try to create another set of sidebar,footer and header in other language and try to create a diffrent page called French left sidebar .In french content  if i select the page as shown below:

[image]

.and on the site when i select the language as english  sidebar content displayed in french language .

so my question is how to get the sidebar content in different language when  different language from the combobox are selected.

Comment: Are the sidebar layouts different or is it just that you want to localise the text? If you could have one sidebar template with localised text would that work for you?

Comment: the sidebars format for all the languages are same .only the content should be in different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new page template that loads a custom sidebar. Also checkout http://wpml.org/2011/06/how-to-build-different-sidebars-per-language/